# How to change class instance outside the class with functions?

Tags: python

I want to change few variables value from `class Person` present in `parent.py` file with `updated.py` file without changing original `class`.

`parent.py` file:

```
already_defined = "no extra"

class Person(object):
    schoolname = 'ENT Medi'
    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname):
        self.address = "{} {}".format(firstname,lastname) # **"this req to change"**
        print(self.address)
    def extra_curr(already_defined):
        newvar = "somthing new" # "**this req to change**"
        print(newvar)
```

This is my `updated.py` file:

```
from parent.py import *

Person.schoolname = "English Medium"
# Person.extra_curr.newvar = "Changed to new"

new = Person()
print(new.schoolname)  # -> English Medium
```

`Person.schoolname` change works, but how to change `self.address` and `newvar` which are inside `__init__` and `extra_curr`?

How to insert external variable value inside the `class` without replacing original `class`?

What I want is below changes without any further modification:

```
self.address = "No address present"
newvar ="just demo var"
```

Comment: To change the value of the attribute of an existing instance of the class, you would need to do something (in this case) like: `new.address = "No address present"`. You cannot change the value of the local variable named `newvar ` inside the `extra_curr()` method from outside the class (or inside it for that matter) except by changing the code in the method itself.

Answer (score 1):

just as martineau wrote in his comment, you cannot change the value of a variable that is declared inside a function from outside that function. That's because the [scope](https://python-textbok.readthedocs.io/en/1.0/Variables_and_Scope.html) of that variable is limited to that function only.

> A variable which is defined inside a function is local to that function. It is accessible from the point at which it is defined until the end of the function, and exists for as long as the function is executing.

if you want to have the ability to change the variable `newvar`  then create it as a class attribute before the `__init__` method such as the following:

```
    class Person(object):

    newvar = "somthing new"
    schoolname = 'ENT Medi'

    def __init__(self,firstname,lastname):
        self.address = "{} {}".format(firstname,lastname) # **"this req to change"**


        print(self.address)
```

Then you can just write:

`Person.newvar ="just demo var"`

Comment: what happens when `extra_curr` func executed which `newvar` it will print

Comment: it will print ```newvar``` that is defined inside the function ```extra_curr```.